# Intent to another activity in ArrayAdapter - Error on Nexus-5

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm having a device specific error which is kind of strange.
In my `ArrayAdapter` I have an `ImageView` and on click the `ImageView` it go to a new `Activity`. This all works well on my Samsung S4 (API 19) but on my Nexus5 (API 22) it's crashing with no error log.

This is my code:

**FArrayAdapter.java**

```
public FArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<Feeds> feedsList) {
    super(context, resourceId, feedsList);
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.mfeeds = feedsList;
    this.inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_t_1);



   ....
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, ZActivity.class);

   if (image1 != null) {
        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent.putExtra("SelectedImagePosition", 1);
                Log.v("Error","here"); //i can see this log when i click. App crashes soon after.
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: where you initialized `image1`?

Comment: edited..i do that above

Answer (score 1):

First, Always try for not to implement listner inside adapter.

You should implement item listener in your fragment like:

```
 View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = v.getTag().toString();
        }
    };
```

If you want to pass any information in activity via intent you should set value in tag like:

in your adapter, you should pass that listner object via constructor from fragment.

and under getView() method:

```
image1.setOnClickListener(listener);
image1.setTag(value); //set value as either class object or any single value here
```

Comment: yeah but i have to pass information to the activity through an intent. That information is in the adapter. How can i get that in my activity

Comment: Thanks. but the problem is when i click the image i want to send the image path of the image clicked and the string of the textview below it. So my question is how can i get the value of an item which is not clicked (i.e. the textview)

Comment: As per your snippiest code, it seems like, you have object of Feeds where you have path of image and text which you are setting, if it is true, you can set that Feeds object in view.setTag(Feeds) and on item click, you can get that over there, where you can get both things.

Comment: this doesn't work if i have multiple imageviews and i want to set listener to each imageview

Comment: This should work in any scenario if you have multiple image view as well.

Comment: so i tried to set `image1.setTag("image1");` `image2.setTag("image2")` and in my `onItemClick`. when i do view.getTag() it returns me null